# Roblox game auto detector

Tags: lua, roblox

ok so I'm making a gui and it auto detects what game ur in.. only problem is if ur in a game it doesn't support its supposed to kick you and leave a message

```
if game.GameId == "301549746" then
    btxt.Text = "Game detected, Counter-Blox"
end
if game.GameId == "137877687" then
    btxt.Text = "Game detected, Rociticens"
end
if game.GameId == "286090429" then
    btxt.Text = "Game detected, Aresenal"
end

if else 
    game.Players.LocalPlayer:Kick("game not supported");
end
```

for some reason i cant use else in this situation
it just underlines "else" in red and then wont run

Comment: i couldnt understand The sentence "i cant else in this code becuase it erros", are you saying, the code has a runtime error??

Comment: i meant i cant use else in that situation im not sure why, it just underlines "else" in red and then wont run at all

Answer (score 0):

you should use elseif thus the statement only run once and else keyword has to be place before the end of statement

When you write nested ifs, you can use elseif. It is similar to an else followed by an if, but it avoids the need for multiple ends:

https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.1.html

Comment: yes that still errors though ive tried elseif, else do, if else. all the good suff

Comment: @Chrons, take a look at the code sample at PONGPONG's link. Are you structuring your code like this : `if <condition> then  ... elseif <condition> then ... else ... end` ?